# Ant gwtcompile ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, gwt, ant, gxt

I have set up the following task with ant to compile my gwt project.

```
    <taskdef resource="dk/contix/ant/gwt/ant-gwt.xml" classpathref="gwt.classpath" />
    <gwtcompile destdir="${www.dir}" optimize="true" version="1.6">
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.gwt.xml"/>
      </fileset>
    </gwtcompile>
```

I get this error:

```
[gwtcompile] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[gwtcompile] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/shell/PlatformSpecific
[gwtcompile]    at dk.contix.ant.gwt.GWT16Compile$1.run(GWT16Compile.java:40)
[gwtcompile]    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
[gwtcompile]    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
[gwtcompile]    at dk.contix.ant.gwt.GWT16Compile.execute(GWT16Compile.java:50)
[gwtcompile]    at dk.contix.ant.gwt.GWTCompileTask.execute(GWTCompileTask.java:136)
[gwtcompile]    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[gwtcompile]    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
[gwtcompile]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[gwtcompile]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
[gwtcompile]    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[gwtcompile]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[gwtcompile]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
[gwtcompile]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
[gwtcompile]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[gwtcompile]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[gwtcompile]    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[gwtcompile]    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[gwtcompile]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[gwtcompile]    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
[gwtcompile]    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
[gwtcompile] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.PlatformSpecific
[gwtcompile]    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[gwtcompile]    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[gwtcompile]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[gwtcompile]    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[gwtcompile]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
[gwtcompile]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
[gwtcompile]    ... 20 more
```

So, with a lot of research, I finally found an old gwt-dev-linux.jar file. When I add this to the class path, I get:

```
[gwtcompile] Comiling modules [com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.ui.ImageViewer]
[gwtcompile] Comiling modules [com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.ui.ImageViewer]
[gwtcompile] Loading module 'com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.ui.ImageViewer'
[gwtcompile]    Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.user.User'
[gwtcompile]       Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.animation.Animation'
[gwtcompile]          Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
[gwtcompile]             Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.CompilerParameters'
[gwtcompile]                [ERROR] Line 23: Unexpected element 'define-configuration-property'
[gwtcompile]                [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
[gwtcompile] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
```

Which the forums say is because of an old version of dev in the class path.

Now I'm stuck and have no idea where to go. Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's IMO no single reason to use this (outdated) ant task (it only works with GWT 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6). Simply use a `java` task to call the `com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler` class.

The following is inspired by the Ant `build.xml` file generated by GWT's [`WebAppCreator`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html#create):

```
<java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler"
    classpathref="gwt.classpath">
  <!-- add jvmarg -Xss16M or similar if you see a StackOverflowError -->
  <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
  <arg line="-war"/>
  <arg value="${www.dir}"/>
  <!-- Additional arguments like -style PRETTY or -logLevel DEBUG -->
  <arg value="com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.ui.ImageViewer"/>
</java>
```

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/tools/templates/ant/build.xmlsrc for the template used by the `WebAppCreator`.

Answer (score 0):

The cool thing about java is that if you get stuck you can always try searching for source code...

Here you can check the code for GWT16Compile: http://code.google.com/p/ant-gwt/source/browse/trunk/src/dk/contix/ant/gwt/GWT16Compile.java?r=12

around line 40 it says:

```
if (config.isOptimize()) {
   updater = PlatformSpecific.checkForUpdatesInBackgroundThread(logger, CheckForUpdates.ONE_DAY);
}
```

Maybe you can try with setting optimize to false in your ant build config and see if it will work.